# postgresql replace 0 with "NULL"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to replace 0 values of a row with just empty (NULL) values in the output.
I'm working with a subquery in the select though, and I'm not entirely clear on how to do this.
This is my query so far:

```
select spelersnr, (select count(bedrag) from boetes where boetes.spelersnr = S.spelersnr
) as aantalboetes

from spelers S inner join wedstrijden using(spelersnr)
left join boetes using(spelersnr)
group by spelersnr


order by aantalboetes asc, spelersnr asc
```

In addition, I first need to sort all the values that are not NULL in ascending order, then the null values.

Thanks!

Comment: If the speler with spelersnummer=0 is not present in the spelers table, the boetes (or wedstrijden) rows with number=zero will not occur in the result anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need the subquery.  The following should do the same thing, because you are already joining in the `boetes` table by the same column used for both aggregation and the correlated subquery:

```
select spelersnr, count(bedrag) as aantalboetes
from spelers S inner join
     wedstrijden
     using(spelersnr) left join
      boetes using(spelersnr)
group by spelersnr
order by aantalboetes asc, spelersnr asc;
```

With this query, you can just do:

```
select spelersnr,
       (case when count(bedrag) > 0 then count(bedrag) end) as aantalboetes
from spelers S inner join
     wedstrijden
     using(spelersnr) left join
      boetes using(spelersnr)
group by spelersnr
order by aantalboetes asc, spelersnr asc;
```

Actually, you could put the same `case` in your version as well:

```
select spelersnr,
       (select (case when count(bedrag) > 0 then count(bedrag) end)
        from boetes
        where boetes.spelersnr = S.spelersnr
       ) as aantalboetes
```

But the correlated subquery is unnecessary.

For the order by, just do:

```
order by count(*) desc
```

You can order by a column not included in the `select` statement, and this is the logic you are looking for.

Comment: Just a passing tip on readability: "`using(spelersnr) left join`" doesn't seem to "belong" as a separate line; it would be much clearer to put "`inner join wedstrijden using(spelersnr)`" on one line (or two, especially if the `on`/`using` was longer) and "`left join boetes using(spelersnr)`" on the next. I've observed people taking a lot less care laying out SQL than just about any other language for some reason.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you, I actually am practising on subqueries so I've left it in. The case did the trick ;)

Answer (score 6):

Replacing a value with a null is simple, using the NullIf() function. Typically it would be used to avoid a division-by-zero error ...

```
numerator/NullIf(denominator,0)
```

... so division by zero results in a null.

In your case you can apply it to the count(*):

```
NullIf(count(*),0)
```